Finite Rank + Integral implies Finitely-Generated?
Let $B$ be a domain which is an integral extension of a regular Noetherian domain $A$ of finite rank ($B \otimes \operatorname{Frac}(A)$ is finite-dimensional over $\operatorname{Frac}(A)$). Is $B$ a finitely-generated module over $A$?
The motivation comes from trying to see what assumptions we need to define discriminants, with $A=\mathbb{Z}$. I know that if $B$ is the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ then $B$ is finitely-generated and free. But to use that sort of argument here it seems I would need to know $\operatorname{Frac}(B)$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. I also haven't been able to generate a counterexample because the finite-rank but not finitely-generated modules I can come up with (e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$ itself) aren't integral over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Please check out How to ask a good question. In particular, please add what you have tried so far, and where this problem comes from. Pure "problem statement" questions are likely to get closed.

Hint: Take a non-normal domain and consider its integral closure in its field of fractions.

@MartinBrandenburg I've updated the question with more info, thank you for the advice
